# reading from txt file and display all contents as bold

Tags: java, swing, text-files, jtextarea, jeditorpane

I want to read my txt file and show it on the screen in bold characters. How can I do that? 
I do some things but I couldn't complete my code actually.

Comment: When you create a new Font you can specify Font.BOLD as one of the parameters.

new Font("serrif", Font.BOLD, 12);

You have done this as part of a coniditional statement. Ifyou remove the condition do you get bold font

Comment: 1) Why does this code extend `Applet`? Is the code intended to be run as both an applet and application? 2) What is the content of the text file?  Is it an application resource like a help file or EULA? 3) **Don't mix Swing and AWT components.**  Use Swing consistently.

Comment: If you see any components on-screen in the applet, it is because the `try` has failed.  There should be a stack-trace in the Java Console.

Comment: extend from button "kalın" , how can i do the whole txt bold?

Comment: I want to make the whole txt seem to be bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code, which is working and tested in my system.

```
public class DisplayText extends Applet implements ItemListener {

    private JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea("", 8, 40);

    private Checkbox Kalin;

    public void init() {

        area1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        File file = new File("D:\\Denemeler\\deneme1.txt");

        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer fileText = new StringBuffer();
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            fileText.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        area1.setText(fileText.toString());

        add(area1);
        Kalin = new Checkbox("Kalin");
        Kalin.addItemListener(this);
        add(Kalin);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)

    {
        int KalinAyari;
        if (Kalin.getState()) {
            KalinAyari = Font.BOLD;
        } else {
            KalinAyari = Font.PLAIN;
        }

        area1.setFont(new Font("Serif", KalinAyari, 14));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: last question, what if I dont want to use check box or button, to be bold, only I want to make the whole txt be bold ??

Comment: I remove the itemlistener and itemstatechanged and implements for that

Comment: If you want your text to be bold without a button click or check box user click, then just use this code after you set the text in the TextArea  "area1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD , 14));"

Comment: ok then I did, and it compiles thank you :))